# regex matches \n in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i need to escape the special characters, so i have checked the regex options like as below,
`new Regex(@"^[\w@.-]*$",RegexOptions.Compiled);`  it's working fine for all special character except \n so how can i check it for all special character.

Comment: i need value of false for this one. it returns false to all characters like \r \t\n new Regex(@"^[\w@.-]*$",RegexOptions.Compiled).IsMatch("Jan\n") but when using \n it returns true.

Comment: you have to explicit which chars you want to allow. \w allows just letters

Comment: but it allows, \n from string "jan\n", can you share me the code

Comment: $ will match the newline character at the end of the string.

Comment: if removed the $also same probem.

Comment: new Regex(@"^[\w@.-]*$",RegexOptions.Compiled); i need the regex will be valid only for numbers and strings not \t\n\r\b like that

Comment: `^[\w@.-]*$` won't match any newline

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead assertion:

`^[\w@.-]*(?!\n)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC3vO2/1).